Various worshippers of the mahavidyas
Can anyone provide the list of upasakas of mahavidyas and some sources from where we can learn the various methods used by these upasakas. For example we have Ramakrishna for Kali Upasana, bamakhepa for maa Tara . What are the examples of other upasakas?
